# Add contact to community

Tags: contact, community

I have a community called developer in my org.I want to add a contact to this community.but when I click Members tab in community edit,I can only add a profile to community.
So how do I add a contact to community ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out: http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf

Scroll to Page 9 for the section: **Adding Members to Your Community**

Comment: it says adding users using profiles or permission sets.I want to add a contact to community.Do I have to add the contact to a profile or permission set for this ?

Comment: yes, you make the contact a portal user and then add that user's profile or perm set to the community.

Comment: to enable as Partner Portal user: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=partner_portal_creating_partner_users.htm&language=en

Answer (score 1):

This has me baffled as well. As Ryan Guest says, its in:

http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf

... but you have to go to the **Creating Communities Users** section on page 23/24, then see "2. To create customer users ..."

The first step is to go to the Contact page, then at the top there is a button called "Manage External User", it has a drop-down option called "Enable Customer User" ... from there on it gets a little more obvious.